# Accessing the active custom node tree in a script

Tags: python, scripting

I'd like to access the active custom custom node tree in the Python code.
It can be done through

```py
    bpy.data.node_groups["name of the custom node tree"]
```

However there could be many node trees of the same type, so the name of the currently open node tree is unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there could be any type of nodetrees in `bpy.data.node_groups`, their names are **unique** and used as **Identifiers**.

So `bpy.data.node_groups['Name of the Nodetree']` means exactly the nodetree with that name, no matter what type it has.

About the active node_tree you need to use the Node Editor's context, either by checking if the active node or the active node_tree is a node_group.

For example, if you have a custom node in a node_tree, and you want to access the node_tree itself from that node, you can look in the context:

`node_tree = bpy.context.space_data.edit_tree`

This will return the current tree being edited in the editor.

Comment: So can you provide a code snippet to get access to the active node tree?

Comment: it depends from where you are (editor), and which nodetree you want to access (material/world/compositor/nodegroup/etc). There are plenty of possibilities, so you need to describe exactly what's your user case.

Comment: I have a number of custom node trees of the same type in Blender 2.80. They can be found in `bpy.data.node_groups`. Is more information required?

Comment: I'd like to access the node tree in the method `insert_link(..)` of a custom node.

Comment: I've updated the answer! ;)